# Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 404 in Vuejs with axios getting API

Tags: javascript, vue.js, promise, async-await, axios

im consume API in vuejs v2 with axios, before im try on directory 1 is working but im try again on directory isn't working. i don't know why is axios configuration it same

**this my code:**

````
      try {
        const response = await this.axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users");
        this.users = response.data;
        console.log(response.data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("error diget, " + error);
      }
    }```

**im try to is code:**

``` this.axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
.then(Response => console.log(Response)))
.catch(Response => console.error(Response))```

but again and again its not working

error code :
``` Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 404
    at createAxiosError (utils.js?c786:148)
    at Object.settle (utils.js?c786:127)
    at handleRequest (handle_request.js?da0c:126)
    at eval (index.js?94db:26)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at MockAdapter.eval (index.js?94db:25)
    at dispatchRequest (dispatchRequest.js?5270:52) ```
````

Comment: 404 is the server returning "not found". Look at the request you are sending

Comment: I checked this url with axios, it works: https://codesandbox.io/s/axios-forked-lcjel?file=/src/index.js

Comment: i try again and this code error if am use axios-mock-adapter